# Trying to change auto increment start value in my tables with Flask SqlAlchemy event.listen.But I am encountering table doesn't exist

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

**models.py**

```
#imports
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'userstore'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
    role = db.Column(db.String(15))
    created_on = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, default=datetime.now())
    logged_in = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)

#Here i am trying to change autoincment vaue
event.listen(User.__table__,"after_create",db.engine.execute(""" ALTER TABLE userstore AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000001""")
)
```

> Also tried to use DDL like

```
event.listen(User.__table__,"after_create", DDL(""" ALTER TABLE userstore AUTO_INCREMENT =100000001"""))
```

when using DDL, migration ran without any errors but id value still starts from 1 which means DDL query inside above event.listen is not executed somehow

> app.py

```
#imports

from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from models import User, Patient,MedicineDetails

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

#route codes

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

> Error after performing
> `flask db init`

```
qlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1146 (42S02): Table 'hms.userstore' doesn't exist
[SQL:  ALTER TABLE userstore AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000001]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: I'm not versed in Flask or SQLAlchemy but the error says that table userstore doesn't exist. Are you sure that it does exist when the Alter Table is run against it?

Comment: No they won't exist initially that's why i am using event listener's "after_create" to invoke the DDL when tables are created using flask migration commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this one:

```
event.listen(User.__table__,"after_create",db.engine.execute(""" ALTER TABLE userstore AUTO_INCREMENT = 100000001"""))
```

is that the `db.engine.execute()` call is going to run immediately, not when the event fires.

I believe the correct version is your second one, which will cause the SQL statement to run when the table is created.

```
event.listen(User.__table__,"after_create", DDL(""" ALTER TABLE userstore AUTO_INCREMENT =100000001"""))
```

Running `flask db init` does not cause any tables to be created. You will need to create a migration with `flask db migrate` and then execute the migration with `flask db upgrade`. Only at that point the event will fire.

Comment: Thanks for helping, after lots of looking around I realized that the second one containing DDL is correct one and the event is only invoked when you explicitly do `db.create_all()` which was missing from my model file.

Comment: If you are using Flask-Migrate then no, you would not call `db.create_all()`. Instead you would create a migration script (`flask db migrate`) and then run it (`flask db upgrade`) as I mentioned in my answer. Flask-Migrate competes with db.create_all(), you have to pick which method you want to use to maintain your database schema.